# Need custom comments functionality( beyond comment module) in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-comments

I've already enabled comments module.

For my website i've following requirements:

1. Customers will leave comments about
   vendor service on Pages
2. Vendor will be provided a login who can reply
   comments
3. Only vendors will be able to reply comments

Also I want to restrict some words used in comment author names like "customer".

All I want to whether any module exists with this functionality or I need to do coding myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a custom code job. Drupals default comment system allows anyone to with the correct permissions to comment on nodes.

[comment_reply()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.pages.inc/function/comment_reply/6) will give you a starting block to achieve what you want.